# My python code takes a long time to get list when query changing to json

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask SQLAlchemy, and I've just started python programming.

I have two problems.

First, when I used `offset` and `limit`, `print` have shown a long query.

Second is these query takes too much time when convert query to json data.

Please see my code.

```
    @classmethod
        def get_admin_product_list(cls, request):
            with giftCenter.session_scope() as session:

                products = session.query(Product.goods_id,
                                         Product.goods_name,
                                         Product.brand_id,
                                         Product.price,
                                         Product.disc_price,
                                         Product.goods_image_id,
                                         Product.goods_desc,
                                         Product.sb_brand_id,
                                         Product.id,
                                         Product.goods_brand_name,
                                         Product.link_company_id,
                                         Product.is_use)

                print('-----1st query-----')
                print(products)
                print('')

                if 'query' in request:
                    query = json.loads(request['query'])
                    filters = query['filters']
                    for key, value in filters.items():
                        try:
                            products = products.filter(getattr(Product, key).ilike("%" + str(value) + "%"))
                        except AttributeError:
                            pass

                print('-----2nd query-----')
                print(products)
                print('')

                total_cnt = products.count()

                order_by = desc('goods_id')

                if 'sortField' in request and 'sortDir' in request:
                    if request['sortField'] is not None and request['sortDir'] == 'desc':
                        order_by = desc(request['sortField'])
                    elif request['sortField'] is not None and request['sortDir'] == 'asc':    
                        order_by = asc(request['sortField'])

                print(order_by)
                print('')

                products = products.order_by(order_by)

                print('-----3rd query-----')
                print(products)
                print('')

                if 'page' in request:
                    page = 1
                    limit = 10

                    if 'page' in request:
                        if type(request['page']) == int or request['page'] is not 0:
                            page = int(request['page'])
                    if 'limit' in request:
                        if type(request['limit']) == int or request['limit'] is not 0:
                            limit = int(request['limit'])
                    if 'offset' in request:
                        if type(request['offset']) == int:
                            offset = int(request['offset'])
                        else:
                            offset = (page - 1) * limit
                    else:
                        offset = (page - 1) * limit

                    print(offset, limit)
                    # products = products.slice(offset, limit)
                    products = products.offset(offset).limit(limit)

                print('-----4th query-----')
                print(products)
                print('')

                data = []

                print('-----before for loop-----')
                print('')

                for product in products:
                    print(product)
                    obj = {
                        "goods_id": product.goods_id,
                        "goods_name": product.goods_name,
                        "brand_id": product.brand_id,
                        "price": product.price,
                        "disc_price": product.disc_price,
                        "goods_image_id": product.goods_image_id,
                        "goods_desc": product.goods_desc,
                        "sb_brand_id": product.sb_brand_id,
                        "id": product.id,
                        "goods_brand_name": product.goods_brand_name,
                        "link_company_id": product.link_company_id,
                        "is_use": product.is_use
                    }
                    data.append(obj)

                    ######## 2nd code
                    # obj = cls.dummy()
                    # setattr(obj, "goods_id", product.goods_id)
                    # setattr(obj, "goods_name", product.goods_name)
                    # setattr(obj, "brand_id", product.brand_id)
                    # setattr(obj, "price", product.price)
                    # setattr(obj, "disc_price", product.disc_price)
                    # setattr(obj, "goods_image_id", product.goods_image_id)
                    # setattr(obj, "goods_desc", product.goods_desc)
                    # setattr(obj, "sb_brand_id", product.sb_brand_id)
                    # setattr(obj, "id", product.id)
                    # setattr(obj, "goods_brand_name", product.goods_brand_name)
                    # setattr(obj, "link_company_id", product.link_company_id)
                    # setattr(obj, "is_use", product.is_use)
                    # data.append(obj.__dict__)

                print('')
                print(data)

                return 0, "OK", data if len(data) else None, total_cnt
```

And this is my printed in log

```
-----1st query-----
SELECT products.goods_id AS products_goods_id, products.goods_name AS products_goods_nam_1, products.brand_id AS products_bra_2, products.price AS products_price, products.disc_price AS products_disc_pric_3, products.goods_image_id AS products_goods_ima_4, products.goods_desc AS products_goods_des_5, products.sb_brand_id AS products_sb_brand__6, products.id AS products_id, products.goods_brand_name AS products_goods_bra_7, products.link_company_id AS products_link_comp_a, products.is_use AS products_is_use 
FROM products

-----2nd query-----
SELECT products.goods_id AS products_goods_id, products.goods_name AS products_goods_nam_1, products.brand_id AS products_bra_2, products.price AS products_price, products.disc_price AS products_disc_pric_3, products.goods_image_id AS products_goods_ima_4, products.goods_desc AS products_goods_des_5, products.sb_brand_id AS products_sb_brand__6, products.id AS products_id, products.goods_brand_name AS products_goods_bra_7, products.link_company_id AS products_link_comp_a, products.is_use AS products_is_use 
FROM products

goods_id DESC

-----3rd query-----
SELECT products.goods_id AS products_goods_id, products.goods_name AS products_goods_nam_1, products.brand_id AS products_bra_2, products.price AS products_price, products.disc_price AS products_disc_pric_3, products.goods_image_id AS products_goods_ima_4, products.goods_desc AS products_goods_des_5, products.sb_brand_id AS products_sb_brand__6, products.id AS products_id, products.goods_brand_name AS products_goods_bra_7, products.link_company_id AS products_link_comp_a, products.is_use AS products_is_use 
FROM products ORDER BY products.goods_id DESC

0 10

-----4th query-----
SELECT products_goods_id, products_goods_nam_1, products_bra_2, products_price, products_disc_pric_3, products_goods_ima_4, products_goods_des_5, products_sb_brand__6, products_id, products_smartcon__7, products_smartcon__8, products_goods_bra_9, products_link_comp_a, products_is_use 
FROM (SELECT products_goods_id, products_goods_nam_1, products_bra_2, products_price, products_disc_pric_3, products_goods_ima_4, products_goods_des_5, products_sb_brand__6, products_id, products_smartcon__7, products_smartcon__8, products_goods_bra_9, products_link_comp_a, products_is_use, ROWNUM AS ora_rn 
FROM (SELECT products.goods_id AS products_goods_id, products.goods_name AS products_goods_nam_1, products.brand_id AS products_bra_2, products.price AS products_price, products.disc_price AS products_disc_pric_3, products.goods_image_id AS products_goods_ima_4, products.goods_desc AS products_goods_des_5, products.sb_brand_id AS products_sb_brand__6, products.id AS products_id, products.goods_brand_name AS products_goods_bra_7, products.link_company_id AS products_link_comp_a, products.is_use AS products_is_use 
FROM products ORDER BY products.goods_id DESC) 
WHERE ROWNUM <= :param_1 + :param_2) 
WHERE ora_rn > :param_2

-----before for loop-----

('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')
('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah')

[{'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}, {'goods_brand_name': 'blah', 'is_use': 'blah', 'brand_id': 'blah', 'link_company_id': 'blah', 'disc_price': 'blah', 'id': 'blah', 'goods_name': 'blah', 'price': 'blah', 'goods_desc': 'blah', 'goods_id': 'blah', 'goods_image_id': 'blah', 'sb_brand_id': 'blah'}]
```

In the line where printed 4th query, you can see it have three select queries. I just used `offset` and `limit` before that query.

And after 'before loop' printed, it takes about 1 seconds to print next line.

When if making `limit` 50, then takes almost 3 seconds.

I've given up 5 columns to reduce spending time, but this was not enough.

Why this happened?

What did I miss something? I have no idea.

Please help me solving this problem.

Welcome any ideas or any links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have I get down voted? This question is for reducing time in query, not for to get working query. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for offset and limit, the query is actually ok. It is just oracle way to do offset and limit.

This query and dict creation code should not be slow, search for lost time elsewhere. Surround suspected slow statements in print(datetime()) to see how much they take.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion. I've printed datetime and I could check it took about 2.5 seconds between 'before for loop' and  first 'product' printing.

Comment: is there an index on product.goods_id ? I assumed there is, but if this is not the case, that can be source of lost time.

Comment: Yes. it's not primary key, it' like '0000000392'. I've removed 'goods_id' on query and object, now I could reduce half. Still remains 1.2 seconds. Thanks to your great helpful point. :)

Comment: To clarify, it is `ORDER BY products.goods_id` clause that requires index. A large `offset` value could also be causing this, regardless of presence of index.

Comment: I've tried changing `order_by = desc('goods_id')` to other column, but any effects not appeared. :(  And I have to get 'goods_id'. My senior said 'Let it be'. lol. There's any other way for reducing time?